Time derivative of a stochastic process
I'm studying stochastic differential equations, but I'm stucked in this problem and I'd like to ask if anyone can suggest me how to solve it in a rigorous way, since I am strongly tempted to simplify the differential $dt$ and then make the substitution, knowing that it is not conceptually correct.
Up to this point, I've already computed $dY_t$ thanks to Ito's lemma.
What is not clear to me is how to compute and the meaning of the derivative $$\frac{dY_t}{dt}$$
Here's the text of the problem:
Given the stochastic differential $$dX_t = \frac{1}{X_t}dt +\sigma X_tdW_t$$ let's define the processes $$F_t = e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t-\sigma W_t}$$ and $$Y_t = X_tF_t$$ whose stochastic differential is given by $$dY_t = \frac{F_t}{X_t}dt$$ and by writing $X_t = \frac{Y_t}{F_t}$, prove that $$\frac {dY_t}{dt}= \frac{F_t^2}{Y_t}$$ with $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X_0=x, Y_0 = x$.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Agree with AnotherUser on content. HINT: Ito's lemma

The rigorous way is to use Ito calculus to show $dY_t = \frac{F_t}{X_t},dt$. Then there is nothing more to prove.

The stochastic differential $dY_t=\frac{F_t}{X_t}dt$ is the outcome of a previous question and I computed it thanks to Ito's lemma, but the problem now is to compute the time derivative $\frac{dY_t}{dt}$

To be clear stochastic processes with Brownian motion are not differentiable in time because Brownian motion isn't. So $\frac{dY_t}{dt}$ is not possible to compute,instead it is only interpreted as an integral
$$Y_{t}=\int....$$
Now to compute $dY=d(XF)$, we use the product rule for Itô Product Rule for Ito Processes
$$dY=FdX+XdF+d[X,F]=\frac{F}{X}dt+FX\sigma dW_t+XF\sigma^2dt-\sigma XFdW_{t}-\sigma^2 XFdt=\frac{F}{X}dt,$$
where we used that $dF=\sigma^2 F dt-\sigma FdW_t$.
